# problem with database, not echoing data correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to create a simple question/ answer website for coding experience. At the home page, you type the question in, and then the question and the person's name are stored in a database, then echoed on another page. I am having trouble getting the data to display on the second page.

Here is the INSERT statement:

```
if ($name && $question) {
safe_query($db, 'INSERT INTO questions (Name, Question) VALUES (%s, %s)',
    $name, $question);
redirect('answers.php/'.$name);
}
```

Here is the SELECT statement:

```
$result = safe_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM questions where name=%s', $name);
if (!$result->num_rows) die('Question not found.');
$question = $result->fetch_object()->question;
```

Comment: Have you checked if the insert query succeeds? Have you checked if the select works?

Comment: yes, the insert works. how would we check if the select works?

Comment: I don't know what DB library you're using in the background, they generally return FALSE or an error object if a query fails. If the query fails, then $result is unlike to have a num_rows attribute/method. Try doing `var_dump($result)` to see what it contains.

Comment: 'var_dump($result)' returns this: 'object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } '

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things missing that make it difficult to answer your question.  Without knowing what you have, one way to check if you have data in mysql is to login and check at the command line.

> mysql -h (hostname) -u (username)
>
> use questions;
>
> SELECT * FROM questions;

Next, not sure what your "safe_query" function is or what it's doing and returning.  Assuming $db is your database object and you are looking for at most one result :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions where Name='{$name}'", $db) or die('Question not found.');

if ( $db->mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $result_arr = $db->mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $question = $result_arr['Question'];

    echo $question;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is called Question, you need `$result->fetch_object()->Question` instead - properties are case sensitive.

Comment: We have: Databse: mark    Table Name:questions  And 2 fields or rows: Question(varchar) Name(var char)

Comment: @Austin908 fields are usually called columns in relational databases like MySQL. This would be clearer if you used `SELECT Name, Question from questions ...` (SELECT * is considered bad practice for other reasons too)

Comment: @Austin908 I should add that MySQL considers columns to be case insensitive in queries, so changing your query to `SELECT name, question FROM questions ...` would return the same results but give you the lowercase column names your code expects. It's conventional to name your columns in all lowercase to avoid this kind of ambiguity.